# How was city cleaning financed and organized in the late 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century, cities, public-finance, hygiene

This [answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/12517/24381) about usage of horses contains a brief description of the situation of New York. Are there examples where city cleaning was done by firms or was the communal government responsible for city cleaning in all metropolitan cities?

Was there special taxation for horse owners to finance city cleaning?

Comment: Which part of the world you want to know about? US of A?

Comment: Every bigger city is interesting. I begin the research about that right now. German wikipedia has some information about city cleaning in Hamburg. There was city cleaning a business for private companies until 1886. Maybe I can find information why it becomes after that a comunal responsibility.

Comment: Don't forget the great stink!

Comment: http://www.columbia.edu/~ma820/privatization.nlf.html